# Async support for a custom TokenProvider in monaco-editor?

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

I'm using `monaco-editor` for a custom language I'm building. However, I want to provide a context aware token provider, for this to work I need to create a custom `TokenProvider` which looks like this:

```
export class CustomTokenProvider implements languages.TokensProvider {

    getInitialState(): languages.IState {
        return new CustomTokenState(0);
    }

    tokenize(line: string, state: languages.IState): languages.ILineTokens {

        var result: any = this.callback.invokeMethod<any>("Tokenize", line, state.tokenState);

        return { tokens: result.tokens, endState: new CustomTokenState(result.endState) };
    }
}
```

This executes in a synchronous context, is it possible to make the `CustomTokenProvider` run  asynchronously?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
export class CustomTokenProvider implements languages.TokensProvider {

    async getInitialState(): languages.IState {
        return new CustomTokenState(0);
    }

    async tokenize(line: string, state: languages.IState): languages.ILineTokens {

        var result: any = await this.callback.invokeMethodAsync<any>("Tokenize", line, state.tokenState);

        return { tokens: result.tokens, endState: new CustomTokenState(result.endState) };
    }
}
```

Investigation: Digging through the monaco-editor types, I can see that you can inherit from `Thenable<languages.TokensProvider>` but I can't seem to understand how this works and I do not think it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to provide a promise from your async method. This is exactly what `Thenable` means.
In custom completion provider it looks this way:

```
//start typing the word 'ohhh' and wait a second
const myEditor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: '',
    language: "javascript",
    automaticLayout: true,
});


monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('javascript', {
    provideCompletionItems(model, position) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve({
                    suggestions: [
                        {
                            label: 'ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh',
                            insertText: 'привет',
                            preselect: true,
                            kind: 7,
                            range: new monaco.Range(position.lineNumber, 1, position.lineNumber, 1)
                        }
                    ]
                })
            }, 1000)
        })
    }
})
```

`async` method is not mandatory if it returns `Thenable`